# requests using session connection closed

Tags: python-requests

I am new to python (2.7) and trying to create a base class used for sending http requests using `requests` and I have drafted following code.

```
class BaseRequest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = requests.Session()

    def do_post(self, url, payload, headers, timeout):
        response = self.s.request('POST', url,
                                  headers=headers,
                                  data=json.dumps(payload),
                                  timeout=timeout)
        return self._handle_response(response)
}
```

What is the benefit of using `Session`? I googled little bit and one of the benefit using Session is to have cookie persistent which I don't really need. Should I just replace with `requests.post()`?
How do I know the actual connection is closed? If exception was thrown in `s.request` will the connection be closed?

Comment: There is no advantage in using a session in your current code.

Comment: Also you can simple use `self.s.post`, no need to use .request